# Why is Threading.Timer delegate stalling?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

My WPF application starts a Threading.Timer early on in its "bootstrap" process. The timer interval is 100ms and the code in the timer delegate typically takes around 70ms (it performs a number of operations in a series of `for` loops, some of which involve reads from the serial port). After starting the timer, the rest of the application is initialised (types registered with the DI framework, creation of views, viewmodels, various other initialisation functions). During these few seconds, the code executing within the timer delegate completely "stalls". It never fails, and none of its serial reads fail (whether that's purely luck) - the timer code just seems to pause execution for approx 3 seconds.

I can only assume that all this startup stuff (on the UI thread) is getting a higher priority, preventing the timer thread from getting any CPU time. Is there anything I can do about it? Starting the timer later on in the bootstrap process may be an option but I wanted to explore other solutions first.

On a side-note, how does the Threading.Timer handle "re-entrancy" (if that's the correct term), i.e. the timer "ticks" while the previous invocation is still running? Does the next invocation get "queued up" and run when the previous one eventually completes, or do I need to handle it myself?

Answer (score 1):

1) The timer launches its tasks as soon as it needs, no queue. You may check it yourself with scheduling something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Sleep");
Thread.Sleep(10000);
Console.WriteLine("Awaken");
```

You will see some output like this with the period of 1 second:

```
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Sleep
Awaken
Awaken
Awaken
Awaken
...
```

2) You may change thread priority but it probably won't do you any good. All .net timers are not meant for real-time usage. So no, you can do nothing about it.